# Ansible: How to inherit variables?

Tags: ansible

I want to achieve variable inheritance in Ansible. Lets say I have:

**group_vars/all**

```
---
ifaces:
   -   name: eth0
       adress: 10.107.13.236
       netmask: 255.255.255.192
       routes:
           - {from: 10.108.100.34/31, via: 10.107.13.193}
           - {from: 10.108.105.128/31, via: 10.107.13.193}
   -   name: eth1
       adress: 10.112.13.236
       netmask: 255.255.255.192
       gateway: 10.112.13.193
       routes:
           - {from: 10.2.1.0/26, via: 10.112.13.254}
```

Now I want to extend the routes of eth0, like this:

**group_vars/webserver**

```
--- ifaces:
   -   name: eth0
       routes:
           - {from: 1.2.3.34, via: 5.6.7.8}
           - {from: 9.9.9.9/9, via: 5.6.7.8}
```

My desired result is:

```
---
ifaces:
   -   name: eth0
       adress: 10.107.13.236
       netmask: 255.255.255.192
       routes:
           - {from: 10.108.100.34/31, via: 10.107.13.193}
           - {from: 10.108.105.128/31, via: 10.107.13.193}
           - {from: 1.2.3.34, via: 5.6.7.8}
           - {from: 9.9.9.9/9, via: 5.6.7.8}
   -   name: eth1
       adress: 10.112.13.236
       netmask: 255.255.255.192
       gateway: 10.112.13.193
       routes:
           - {from: 10.2.1.0/26, via: 10.112.13.254}
```

So the routes should be extendend and not overwritten. I know about setting `hash_behaviour: merge` in `ansible.cfg` but that does not satisfy my needs, because I want to **append** values to the list stored in routes.

The background is, that I need to be able to define some standard routes (note: this is not limited to routes, it is just an example) and enhance these standards for specific groups instead of overriding them.

Is this possible in Ansible?

Comment: I think this will only be possible with a custom written plugin.

Comment: Can you provide me with a starting point how to create such a plugin?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this utility](https://github.com/caredotcom/ansible-quartermaster).  It's basically a "meta" inventory script that will merge inventories from multiple sources, so you can have it combine a dynamic inventory script, multiple static YAML files, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant to add the `{from: 1.2.3.34, via: 5.6.7.8}` and `{from: 9.9.9.9/9, via: 5.6.7.8}` lines rather than copying the first 2 lines again? I've edited it to show that but if that's not the case then roll back my edit.

Comment: I*m new to Ansible, but maybe it would be possible to use two different value-keys, one key as default (e.g. with prefixed "default_") and the other one in the group. [Combined with the combine-filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) might get the wanted result.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating `lookup_plugin` that will do all the heavy-ligting of the merging/appending variables.

for example:

#### lookup_plugins/myvars.py

```
import yaml
class LookupModule(object):
    def __init__(self, basedir=None, **kwargs):
        self.basedir = basedir
        self.plugin_name = 'myvars'
    def run(self, vars_file, variable=None, **kwargs):
        all_routes = yaml.load(file('group_vars/all'))['ifaces'][0]['routes']
        all_routes.extend(
            yaml.load(file('group_vars/%s' % vars_file[0]))['ifaces'][0]['routes'])
        return [all_routes]
```

#### playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - debug: msg=" Hey {{ item }}"
      with_myvars:
        - webservers
```

Of cource it doesn't fully solve your plroblem and you still need to tweak it to make it work. But you should get an idea on how to achive this from this example.

An output of this should look like this:

```
PLAY [webservers] ************************************************************* 

TASK: [debug msg=" Hey {{ item }}"] ******************************************* 
ok: [localhost] => (item=[{'via': '10.107.13.193', 'from': '10.108.100.34/31'}, {'via': '10.107.13.193', 'from': '10.108.105.128/31'}, {'via': '5.6.7.8', 'from': '1.2.3.34'}, {'via': '5.6.7.8', 'from': '9.9.9.9/9'}]) => {
    "item": [
        {
            "from": "10.108.100.34/31",
            "via": "10.107.13.193"
        },
        {
            "from": "10.108.105.128/31",
            "via": "10.107.13.193"
        },
        {
            "from": "1.2.3.34",
            "via": "5.6.7.8"
        },
        {
            "from": "9.9.9.9/9",
            "via": "5.6.7.8"
        }
    ],
    "msg": " Hey [{'via': '10.107.13.193', 'from': '10.108.100.34/31'}, {'via': '10.107.13.193', 'from': '10.108.105.128/31'}, {'via': '5.6.7.8', 'from': '1.2.3.34'}, {'via': '5.6.7.8', 'from': '9.9.9.9/9'}]"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

So as you can see it's returning a list of routes, so you can easily place `{{ item }}` in what ever spot you need.